# MVC - download files - form submit gotten aborted

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

[image]

Above is a screen shot of my download page.  The Action column contains a download link.  This download lick, when clicked, will submit the following form:

```
using (Html.BeginForm(DownloadMainView.ACTION_DOWNLOAD, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    @Html.Hidden("token", Model.Token.Value)
    @Html.Hidden("itemSoftwareCode", item.SoftwareCode)
    @Html.Hidden("downloadingComponent", comp.SoftwareCode)
}
```

The download works fine if I click on one, wait for the download to start, and then click on the next download.  But if I click each download link quickly without wait for the download to start, only the last one get downloaded.  Is there a way to get around this problem where I have to wait for the download to start before clicking on the next download?

Comment: What you see is the normal behavior. when clicking on the link , browser will send that request to server. May be try to improve the response time of your `Download` action  so that it is instantaneous

Comment: Have you considered blocking link clicking for a period of time?  Using javascript/JQuery, etc?

Comment: yes, I've.  But it is a constant guesstimated block time.  So, if the file is small, the block time will be longer than what it should be.  But if the file is big, it will be not long enough.  Not idea solution.  Is there a way to detect download has started?

Comment: Follow example in this link, I'm now able to accurately block the page util download started. ==> http://syper-blogger.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-detect-start-of-file-download.html.  This link basically uses a cookie to determine if download has started.  On client side, it first creates a cookie using js when user clicks the download link.  It then uses window.setInterval to check the cookie every sec.  If the cookie value is updated by the server, download has started.  On the server side, it simply updates the cookie value right before sending the file stream result.